# Custom loss in keras produces misleading outputs during training of an autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have rank-3 tensors of size (100,100,4) that I try to compress and reconstruct with an autoencoder. I use a physically motivated loss function. Mathematically it is

L = - overlap(y_true,y_pred) + |1 - norm(y_pred)^2|

In code it reads:

```py
def physical_loss(y_true,y_pred,norm=None):
    return - tf.tensordot(y_true,y_pred,axes=([0,1,2],[0,1,2])) + tf.math.abs(1 - tf.tensordot(y_pred,y_pred,axes=([0,1,2],[0,1,2])))
```

The first term is the overlap between the input and output tensor (that I want to maximize), the second term keeps the output tensor from exploding and most desirably at norm 1 (overlap between tensor and itself = norm). So ideally the loss goes down to -1 (i.e. y_pred = y_true and norm(y_pred)=1)

My model is a convolutional AutoEncoder that reduces the size to (50,50,4),(25,25,4) and builds it up again.

```py
cnn.compile(loss=physical_loss,optimizer="adam")

cnn.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=16,validation_data=(x_train,x_train))
```

Now when I train my cnn I the loss gradually goes down in 16 epochs eventually reaching val_loss = -0.67. But when I manually check the outcome (i.e. computing the loss between x_train and cnn.predict(x_train) directly myself), on average I obtain 0.75 (positive!).

**So my question is what is keras/tensorflow outputting when evaluating?**

This might be related or another question, but when I cnn.evaluate(x_train,x_train,batch_size=X) the result varies from +0.88 to -0.88 and values in between depending on how I choose the batch size X (gets the same -0.67 when chossing None, so 32). I know keras does everything in batches but this shouldnt alter the overal output no? Also this makes it hard to interpret the output / training success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, the problem is that keras/tensorflow is expecting an already vectorized function. The above definition is intended for rank-3 tensors, but keras/tensorflow is always dealing with batches, so "lists" of rank-3 tensors that are not actually lists but rank-4 tensors (first dimension is the "list").

I found vectorizing this loss function not so trivial but found a working solution with tf.map_fn(function,listed_tensor,dtype) where listed_tensor is the mentioned rank-4 batch.

```py
def single_eval(duo):
    return - tf.tensordot(duo[0],duo[1],axes=([0,1,2],[0,1,2])) + tf.keras.backend.abs(1 - tf.tensordot(duo[1],duo[1],axes=([0,1,2],[0,1,2])))

def physical_loss(y_true,y_pred,norm=None):
    return tf.map_fn(single_eval,(y_true,y_pred),dtype=(tf.float32))
```

The specification of the dtype is necessary in order to be able to use a tuple as an argument (i.e. use two arguments).